# how to get JavaScript value in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am trying to get the result in php with JavaScript variable

```
document.getElementById("pm").innerHTML = +getValue('printermodel');
```

its working fine with below one.

```
<div id="pm"></div>
```

now i want to get the result in php

```
<?php $result=$_GET['pm'];
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: no that is not working for me

Comment: its not duplicate somebody please answer